# Proving a system is linearly independent in a Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

http://i.stack.imgr.com/QfTyD.png

Okay, I've done part (i) but I'm stumped on part (ii) and how I can show that.

Any help would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_ke_k=0\implies\;\forall\,j=1,2,...,n\;,\;:$$

$$0=\left\langle \sum_{k=1}^na_ke_k\,,\,e_j\right\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\langle e_k\,,\,e_j\rangle=a_j$$

and we're done...

Comment: Thankyou for this, but can you tell me what the variable "a" represents? And also, how does this actually show that it is in fact linearly independent? So I know the workings behinds the answer to I understand it.

Comment: $\;a_i\;$ are not variables but *scalars*, and you should read again carefully the definition of "linear independent set" in a vector space

Comment: Just looked it up, makes sense now, thankyou!

Comment: Any time, @user109331...this is stuff you can't allow yourself to forget if you're going to mess up with Hilbert, Banach and stuff spaces...